# IndexError: list index out of range in Topcoder submission

Tags: python, list, indexing, submission

When I ran my code in a [Topcoder problem](https://arena.topcoder.com/#/u/practiceCode/16900/11686/10868/1/329895), it showed that there's an error: IndexError: list index out of range. However the code worked perfectly on the Python IDLE. Could anyone tell me where's wrong?

> Problem Info:
>
> Definition Class:
>
> CheeseSlicing Method: totalArea
>
> Parameters: integer, integer, integer, integer
>
> Returns: integer Method
>
> signature: def totalArea(self, A, B, C, S):
>
> Examples
>
> 0) 1 3 3 2
>
> Returns: 0
>
> One of the dimensions of this block is 1. Regardless of how
>   we cut it, each piece will have one dimension equal to 1. As S=2, this
>   means that producing a good slice is impossible. Hence, the maximum
>   total surface area of good slices is 0.

```
import sys
total=0
data=sys.stdin.read().split()
x,y,z,s=int(data[0]),int(data[1]),int(data[2]),int(data[3])

if min(x,y,z)==s:
    print x*y*z/s

elif min(x,y,z)<s:
    print 0

elif max(x,y,z)>s:
    lines=[x,y,z]
    while max(lines)>=2*s:
        area=1
        maxline=max(lines)
        lines.pop(lines.index(maxline))

        for line in lines:
            area=area*line
        total+=area
        lines.append(maxline-s)
    area=1
    minline=min(lines)
    lines.pop(lines.index(minline))
    for line in lines:
        area=area*line
    total+=area
    print total
```

Comment: I do not know, how this code could perfectly worked in your IDLE. split() function will return list with one item.

Comment: There is a chance Topcoder to have some issues with the validation tests on this problem.

Comment: For example, the input will be '5 5 5 2' and the split() function will return ['5', '5', '5', '2'].

Answer (score 0):

You are getting index error because your `data` is empty due to unexpected  EOF in the test inputs provided by topcoder. You can try implementing your  code to handle the EOF exceptions in between the inputs.

Comment: you can implement exception handling while taking input